# How can Console.Write affect Console.ReadKey in terminal?

Tags: .net-core, logging, console-application

When debugging a program in Visual Studio I experienced some weird behavior from Console.ReadKey.

The main thread is waiting on `Console.ReadKey` while a background thread does some API calls.

The background thread log things via `Console.Write`. At one point the background thread logged the result of an API-call returning a pdf (using `HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync`),   .

This of course writes a lot of binary garbage to the console.

**The strange thing is the printing of binary garbage caused `Console.ReadKey` to detect a key press and exit the program!**

I confirmed this several times and the program works fine if I remove the binary log.

Is there a sequence of control characters that when printed works as keyboard input?

(I solved the issue by filtering out control characters from the log but I am still curious how this works)

If it matters, this is console application on windows. I tested both net6 and net8.